# Is it possible to boost query results based on an unsearched field?

Tags: solr

Our documents have keywords meta, but I only want to return documents for which the keyword is *also* in the content (and then boost the document over other documents where the keyword is *only* in the content)

Can anyone tell me how to do this in SOLR?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can boost a term in the query by using the ^ character. For example

```
q=(keywordField:searchTerm^1000 AND contentField:searchTerm)
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Boosting_Ranking_Terms).